# Can I programmatically create a directory and add a page default.aspx whose content I wish to provide from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I am trying is making a directory for each video upload and in each directory there will be a default.aspx page which will show the video. How can I do this?

What I have tried so far is :-

```
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("~/movies/" + next_id + "-" + Txt_title.Text);
            string filePath="~/movies/" + next_id + "-"+ Txt_title.Text+"/Default.aspx";
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Label1.Text = "Failed!";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(filePath);
             }
```

But after this if I fairly have no clue how to append aspx elements to this file. Please give some hint

Comment: Please show the code ... what you have tried and what problem (issue) you faced?

Comment: Probably better not to create a new page for every video. Instead, have one page that dynamically loads different videos based on the URL.

Comment: I know that but if i create every page with titles my site will rank higher in search engines

Comment: @SohamKrishna Then you can implement a robots.txt file in your server: http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html

Comment: do some reading here - https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ - possibly 'structured data'. also, you can dynamically change the title of the page (search for that), or part of the title. My Movies - [name]  <-- only name changes, for ex.